# Does there exists a sequence ${x_m}$ that simultaneously satisfies two conditions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Does there exists a sequence $x_n$, that simultaneously satisfies:

1. $|x_n| <0,666, \forall n \in \mathbb{N*}$
2. $|x_m-x_n| \ge \frac{1}{n(n+1)} +\frac{1}{m(m+1)}, \forall m \neq n$

**Attempts:**

I have actually been trying to apply the second condition recursively, which means

\begin{align}
|x_m-x_n|=\sum_{i=n}^{m-1} |x_{i+1} -x_i| = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} +\frac{1}{m(m+1)}
\end{align}

Since $|x_{i+1}-x_i|$ has its own inequality, by doing so, I expect the value of $|x_m-x_n|$ to exceed $0,666$ at sometime, but it turns out that the inequality must be reversed.

So is my direction correct, and do you have any idea how to proceed, or any suggestion on an alternate solution?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a sequence does not exist. The following solution is taken from [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h573623p3376792): The intervals
$$
 I_k = \left( x_k-\frac{1}{k(k+1)}, x_k+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)
$$
are pairwise disjoint, so that the Lebesgue measure of $A = \bigcup_k I_k$ is
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{k(k+1)} = 2 \, .
$$
On the other hand, if all $x_k$ are in the range $(-2/3, 2/3)$ then $A$ is contained in an interval of the length
$$
\sup\{  x_k+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\} - \inf\{  x_k-\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\} 
 \underset{(*)}{<} \frac 43 + \frac 1{1 \cdot 2} + \frac 1{2 \cdot 3} = 2 \, .
$$
The reason for the strict inequality at $(*)$ is that either $\frac 43$ or $\frac 1{1 \cdot 2}$ can be replaced by a smaller number, depending on whether $I_1$ is the “leftmost” interval or not.